# I tried everything but not getting spaces in middle of the columns

Tags: css

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"
    integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous" />
</head>
<style>
    @import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Jost:wght@300;400;500;600;700;800&display=swap');
    @import url("https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.3/css/all.min.css");

    #categories{
  text-align: center;
}

#categories h1{
margin-bottom:5rem;
}

.category-blocks h3{
font-size: x-large;
margin: 1rem 0;

}
.category-blocks{
background-color: lightgreen;}
.category-blocks p{
  width: 80%;
margin: 1rem 0;
margin: auto;
text-align: justify;
margin-bottom: 1rem;

}
.category-blocks .btn-primary{
  border-radius: 2rem;
  background-color: transparent;
  border:2px solid #03bf72;
  padding: 0.7rem 1.8rem;
  color: #03bf72;
}
.category-blocks .fas{
  color: #03bf72;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
}

</style>
<body>
    <section id="categories">
        <div class="row">

            <div class="col-md-4 category-blocks">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <i class="fas fa-bullhorn"></i>
                        <h3>Effective Marketing</h3>
                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Earum inventore architecto magni? Sed, laudantium aperiam?</p>
                        <button class="btn btn-primary">Learn more</button>
                </div>
            </div>

            
            <div class="col-md-4 category-blocks">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <i class="fas fa-bullhorn"></i>
                        <h3>Effective Marketing</h3>
                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Earum inventore architecto magni? Sed, laudantium aperiam?</p>
                        <button class="btn btn-primary">Learn more</button>
                </div>
            </div>

            
            <div class="col-md-4 category-blocks">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <i class="fas fa-bullhorn"></i>
                        <h3>Effective Marketing</h3>
                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Earum inventore architecto magni? Sed, laudantium aperiam?</p>
                        <button class="btn btn-primary">Learn more</button>
                </div>
            </div>

            

            









        </div>
    </section>
</body>
</html>
```

I need to set 3 blocks side by side in a page, so I applied 'col-md-4', unfortunately I was not getting space in middle of them even after I tried all the possible ways. Please help me out.

Comment: You have applied the background to the whole column, apply it to the children instead `.category-blocks * {
    background-color: lightgreen;
}`

Answer (score 0):

Why dont you do it with display: flex or maybe display: grid, with that you can do a gap: X and that will do the separation.
NOTE: the gap: X, can be diferent if you are using flex or grid, you can find it in here:
flex - https://coryrylan.com/blog/css-gap-space-with-flexbox
grid - https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/gap

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).